# Can write and read from a script on Firebase?

Tags: unity

I want to post a script on Firebase and connect it with my game. It's possible to make my game write and read from that Firebase?
When Player start a level, Load a script from Firebase. When Player end a level, write on script.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. I could fathom reasons to load scripts at runtime from an online source. But *write* them?!? What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I want to upload a C# to Firebase and connect it with my game. Load from this file the level design "object positions and Color". Write/save a list or numbers "Player clicks/Movements". Is it possible to do that?

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of C# code. An XML or JSON data structure can store this data in a way that's more portable and does not rely on compiling new C# code in the game client (something that mobile platforms generally will not permit you to do).

Comment: OK. Thank you for clearing this point for me.